# Are the Reflections and the Siege of Crystal Empire IDW My Little Pony comic story arcs supposed to be related?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

The Reflection story arc in the My Little Pony official IDW comic is centered around the idea  of alternate universes.

> More specifically, the arc focus on a mirror dimension where every character apparently has an opposite. The two worlds balance each other out, so if any character becomes good on the 'real' side, their reflection becomes evil as a consequence. This is clearly seen with Luna/Nightmare Moon.
>  The story ends with the sacrifice of the alternate Sombra, who uses a spell to absorb the evilness from two other character, becoming evil himself in the process...
>  So, by the end of Reflections, both versions of Sombra are evil: the original one from the show and the mirror one who sacrificed himself.

Given that

> the original Sombra redeems himself at the end of Siege of Crystal Empire and then leaves on a journey with Radiant Hope (a far better outcome to the quite lame retcon Season 9 made of this story...), becoming thus good and balancing out his reflection once again...

Is there any objective proof that the two stories are intended to be tied (writers interview, additional material and so on) or should this be regarded as a pure coincidence?